# Bash commands not found in Git bash shell

Tags: bash, git-bash

I use bash on windows and my Git bash shell commands stopped working, and cannot be fixed even after re-installing Git bash. So `/bin/ls` works but `ls` does not work

I also get the following

```
$ /bin/which ls
/bin/which: no ls in (/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3:/home/user/bin)

$ /bin/which /bin/ls
/bin/ls
```

My windows Path is

```
C:\Users\achaudhuri\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3; 
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\";"C:\Users\achaudhuri\AppData\Roaming\npm"
```

I can't figure where the bin is and what I could do to add it back to path. Could anyone pleas help to fix bash?

Comment: Did you overwrite `PATH` somewhere in your bash?

Comment: `type ls`, not `which ls`. And `ls` isn't a bash command -- it isn't included with bash / part of bash at all; it's a separate executable provided by the OS (or in this case by Cygwin), can be run without using a shell at all (unlike shell-builtins -- `unset`, `declare`, etc, which are only available from inside a shell), and needs to be found by a check of the directories in the PATH variable.

Comment: Check the PATH in *cygwin*, not the one in *Windows*; editing the output from `declare -p PATH` into the question will do. Easiest way to cause this problem is with something like `for PATH in */; do ...; done`, which is why POSIX reserves lower-case variable names as safely usable by applications, so they don't overwrite variables meaningful to the shell itself by mistake.

Comment: ...if you want to figure out where that's happening, `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' /bin/bash -l -i -x` (all on one line, exactly as given, with no semicolons) will log shell startup with each command run, so you can look at where `PATH` is being set and changed.

Comment: Yes, the path was not set correctly in `.bashrc` - overwriting instead of appending, I fixed it and moved it to `.bash-profile` and the problem is fixed now.